How to Implement 'or' Condition in Criteria Query with Spring Data Elasticsearch
I am developing a query builder in Spring Boot using Spring Data Elasticsearch and facing an issue with implementing the or condition in a method designed to filter actions based on multiple possible 'scopes'. Below is the complete code for my QueryBuilder class and the relevant part of the ActionQueryService class:
kotlin
import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.query.Criteria;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.query.CriteriaQuery;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;

class QueryBuilder private constructor() {
    companion object {
        private var criteria: Criteria = Criteria()

        fun init(): Companion {
            criteria = Criteria()
            return this
        }

        fun addActorOidCriterion(actorOid: String?): Companion {
            criteria = criteria.and(actorOid?.let { Criteria(ActionEntity::actorOid.name).`is`(it) })
            return this
        }

        fun addActionTypeCriteria(actionTypes: Set<ActionType>?): Companion {
            if (!actionTypes.isNullOrEmpty()) {
                criteria = criteria.and(ActionEntity::actionType.name).`in`(actionTypes)
            }
            return this
        }

//FIXME: This function doesn't work as expected, it should generate a query to search for any Actions where the field 'scopes' contains any of the scope in the list. Instead of that, it generates a query to search for any Actions where the field 'scopes' contains all the scopes in the list.
        fun addScopesCriteria(scopes: Set<String>?): Companion {
            if (!scopes.isNullOrEmpty()) {
                val scopesQuery = Criteria()

                scopes.forEach { scope ->
                    scopesQuery.or(scopesQuery.contains(scope.lowercase()))
                }

                criteria = criteria.and(scopesQuery)
            }
            return this
        }

        fun addCommitteesCriterion(committees: Set<String>?): Companion {
            if (!committees.isNullOrEmpty()) {
                criteria = criteria.and(Criteria(ActionEntity::committee.name).`in`(committees))
            }
            return this
        }

        fun addAcknowledgeCriterion(acknowledged: Boolean?): Companion {
            acknowledged?.let {
                criteria = criteria.and(Criteria(ActionEntity::acknowledged.name).`is`(acknowledged))
            }
            return this
        }

        fun addExpectedTargetDateBeforeCriterion(expectedTargetDateBefore: ZonedDateTime?): Companion {
            expectedTargetDateBefore?.let {
                criteria = criteria.and(Criteria(ActionEntity::expectedTargetDate.name).lessThan(it))
            }
            return this
        }

        fun addExpectedTargetDateAfterCriterion(expectedTargetDateAfter: ZonedDateTime?): Companion {
            expectedTargetDateAfter?.let {
                criteria = criteria.and(Criteria(ActionEntity::expectedTargetDate.name).greaterThan(it))
            }
            return this
        }

        fun build(pageable: Pageable): CriteriaQuery {
            return CriteriaQuery(criteria).setPageable(pageable)
        }
    }
}

class ActionQueryService {
        fun createCriteriaQuery(filterCriteria: ActionCriteria, pageable: Pageable): CriteriaQuery {
        return ActionQueryBuilder
                .init()
                .addActorOidCriterion(filterCriteria.actorOid)
                .addActionTypeCriteria(filterCriteria.actionTypes?.map { ActionType.valueOf(it) }?.toSet())
                .addScopesCriteria(filterCriteria.scopes)
                .addCommitteesCriterion(filterCriteria.committees)
                .addAcknowledgeCriterion(filterCriteria.acknowledged)
                .addExpectedTargetDateBeforeCriterion(filterCriteria.expectedTargetDateBefore)
                .addExpectedTargetDateAfterCriterion(filterCriteria.expectedTargetDateAfter)
                .build(pageable)
    }
}

fun findByFilterOptions(
        filterCriteria: ActionCriteria,
        pageable: Pageable
    ): DocumentPage {
        filterCriteria.actorOid = filterCriteria.actorOid ?: userProfileService.getByCurrentUser().id.toString()

        val criteriaQuery = actionQueryService.createCriteriaQuery(filterCriteria, pageable)

        val searchHits = elasticOperation.search(criteriaQuery, ActionEntity::class.java)

        val streamable = searchHits.map { it.content }
        return DocumentPage(map(streamable.toList()), searchHits.totalHits)
    }

@Document(indexName = "actions")
data class Action(
    @Id
    var id: UUID,
    @Field(type = FieldType.Keyword)
    var actorOid: String,
    @Field(type = FieldType.Text)
    var scopes: Set<String>?,
    @Field(type = FieldType.Keyword)
    var group: String?,
    @Field(type = FieldType.Date)
    var expectedTargetDate: ZonedDateTime? = null,
    @Field(type = FieldType.Keyword)
    var actionType: ActionType,
    @Field(type = FieldType.Boolean)
    var acknowledged: Boolean = false,
)



Issue:
The addScopesCriteria function should generate a query to search for any Actions where the field 'scopes' contains any of the scope in the list. However, it generates a query to search for Actions where the field 'scopes' contains all the scopes in the list.
Setup:
Spring Boot version: 3.1.5
Spring Data Elasticsearch version: 5.1.5
Expected Behavior:
The method should apply an OR condition across the scopes, allowing for the retrieval of actions containing any of the specified scopes.
Actual Behavior:
It incorrectly applies what seems to be an AND condition, requiring all specified scopes to be present.
it generates the following json query
{
    "from": 0,
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "query_string": {
                        "default_operator": "and",
                        "fields": [
                            "actorOid"
                        ],
                        "query": "xxxxx"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "bool": {
                        "must": [
                            {
                                "query_string": {
                                    "analyze_wildcard": true,
                                    "fields": [
                                        "scopes"
                                    ],
                                    "query": "*aaa*"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "query_string": {
                                    "analyze_wildcard": true,
                                    "fields": [
                                        "scopes"
                                    ],
                                    "query": "*bbb*"
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "size": 20,
    "sort": [
        {
            "expectedTargetDate": {
                "mode": "min",
                "order": "asc"
            }
        }
    ],
    "track_scores": false,
    "version": true
}

There is a 'must' where I want a 'should'.
I suspect there might be a flaw in how I'm chaining or using the .or() method. Could anyone help me correct this implementation to meet the expected behavior?
Thank you very much!
